# Angular *ngIf syntax using directive and not a string parameter

Tags: html, angular, forms, directive, angular-ng-if

I'm reading PluralSight's [article on reactive forms](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/difference-between-template-driven-and-reactive-forms-angular#module-reactiveforms) to refresh my memory and I can't figure out the syntax shown below.

```
<div *ngIf courseForm.get('courseName').valid && courseForm.get('courseName').touched>
  Please enter valid course name !
</div>
```

I can't make it work on my computer, unless I change to the syntax I'm familiar with from before, i.e. a string passed for evaluating the truity like so.

```
<div *ngIf="courseForm.get('courseName').valid && courseForm.get('courseName').touched">
  Please enter valid course name !
</div>
```

If it'd be YAF blog, I'd chalk it up to the author's confusion and/or sloppiness but given the reputation of PluralSight, I'm rather prone to question my competence. However, I haven't found any documentation on the new syntax and I'm a bit stumped. Has PluralSight made a booboo?

Comment: clear error from PluralSight

Comment: @michelepatrassi Don't you find it strange that PluralSight would allow such a grave mistake given their reputation as the go-to-place for fetching new knowledge? Was it your downvote by the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be a mistake, if you look at the [`ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) syntax it states,

> A shorthand form of the directive, *ngIf="condition", is generally
>   used, provided as an attribute of the anchor element for the inserted
>   template.